# login design in prism 4.0

Tags: wpf, prism-4

this question might sound silly. I want to do login page by editing the template in VS2010 with Prism 4.0 as the template. as a login page, it will have 2 textbox, one is username and another one is password. in one button click, i want that button to retrieve both of the value. currently this not happen,because it just carry 1 value. i am new to this MVVM. if i put the code in the view part, perhaps this might violate the model.

this is part of the code (from the template)

```
    <Button prism:Click.Command="{Binding Login}"
    prism:Click.CommandParameter="{Binding Username}" Margin="2"                                        
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to navigate to the Edit View for this item."                        IsCancel="True" IsDefault="False"><Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="/Module1;component/Images/NavigateToView.png" />
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create two new properties in your view model and bind your textboxes to them in xaml

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay} />
<TextBox Text={Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Then, in your `Login` command implementation, you could simply use these properties, as they reflect the data the user has entered in the textboxes. This way you don't have to use a command parameter either.

Comment: i have done that, but that way seems only affect the front end without passing the data

Comment: @ct_anas Try setting `Mode=TwoWay` in the binding (I've updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: ok.noted. now, i need to access the value of username,password. after using binding in xaml. i need to use getbindingexpression,am i right? .my problem now is, i am in moduleviewmodel page, how am i going to import the textbox that i use in the view page?

Comment: @ct_anas Your "moduleviewmodelpage" has the backing properties that you're binding to right (i.e. Username and Password)? Well, when you click the button and invoke the "Login" command, you already have Username and Password so just send it where you want. You have no need for a command parameter in this case; your viewmodel already has the information it needs.

Comment: the viewmodel bring the username and password in the action 
`private void SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` this is the method that i used to retrieve the value